# Como pegar o valor de índice de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python

Estou tentando encontrar uma maneira de encaixar um valor de salário, que é minha variável `sal`, em um intervalo. Eu tenho 8 intervalos:

1. $200 - $299
2. $300 - $399
3. $400 - $499
4. $500 - $599
5. $600 - $699
6. $700 - $799
7. $800 - $899
8. $900 - $999

Mas não posso utilizar vários `if` alinhados. Então coloquei os valores máximos em uma lista e pensei em ir comparando item por item da lista com o valor do salário e depois pegar o indíce do valor da lista como no código abaixo:

```
lista = [299,399,499,599,69,799,699,999]

valor_bruto = float(input("Digite o valor bruto das vendas semanais do funcionário"))
sal = 200 + 0.09*valor_bruto #valor do salario

for n in lista:
    if sal < n:
        c = lista.index(n) #guarda valor do índice em que se encontra o valor do salário

print("O funcionário está no intervalo entre",(lista[c]-99) ,lista[c])
```

Porém o código não está pegando o valor correto do índice. E eu não consigo descobrir o erro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua lista tem um valor `69`, mas acredito que você quis dizer `699`. E depois do `799`, coloque `899` (pois antes estava `699`).

---

É possível percorrer uma lista podendo acessar ao mesmo tempo o índice e o respectivo elemento, usando [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
lista = [299, 399, 499, 599, 699, 799, 899, 999]
valor_bruto = float(input("Digite o valor bruto das vendas semanais do funcionário"))
sal = 200 + 0.09 * valor_bruto # valor do salário
for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
    if sal < valor:
        indice = i # encontrei o índice
        break # saio do loop
print(f"O funcionário está no intervalo entre {lista[indice] - 99} e {lista[indice]}")
```

Ou seja, ao encontrar o índice, eu já posso sair do `for`, usando `break`. Depois, basta imprimir os valores, como você estava fazendo. Eu usei [*f-strings*](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (a string com um `f` antes das aspas), que estão disponíveis a partir do Python 3.6, mas se estiver usando uma versão anterior, também pode fazer assim:

```
print("O funcionário está no intervalo entre {} e {}".format(lista[indice] - 99, lista[indice]))
```

Chamar `index` para obter o índice também funciona, mas [isso fará com que a lista seja percorrida novamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176921), até encontrar o índice do elemento em questão. Mas isso é desnecessário se você percorrer a lista com `enumerate`, pois já terá o índice quando o respectivo valor for encontrado.

---

Outro detalhe é que subtrair 99 pode funcionar para este caso específico, mas e se as faixas de salário forem diferentes? (como por exemplo `[299, 499, 1999]`)

Neste caso, uma maneira mais genérica é verificar se o índice é o primeiro, último ou outro no meio da lista, e formatar a mensagem de acordo com cada caso:

```
for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
    if sal < valor:
        indice = i # encontrei o índice
        break
else:
    indice = - 1

if indice == 0: # primeira faixa
    print(f"O funcionário está no intervalo abaixo de {lista[indice]}")
elif indice == - 1: # depois da última faixa
    print(f"O funcionário está no intervalo acima de {lista[indice]}")
else: # alguma faixa do meio
    print(f"O funcionário está no intervalo entre {lista[indice - 1] + 1} e {lista[indice]}")
```

Agora eu incluí um `else` no `for` (sim, em Python um `for` pode ter um `else` associado), que indica o caso em que o salário não cai em nenhuma das faixas. Ou seja, se o salário não for menor que nenhum dos valores da lista, quer dizer que ele é maior que todos. Neste caso, ele nunca entra no `if sal < valor`, o `break` não é chamado, e isso faz com que caia no `else`. Neste caso, eu seto o índice para `-1`.

Depois, basta verificar a qual faixa de valores o índice corresponde. Se for a primeira (índice é zero), eu apenas indico que o salário está abaixo de tal valor (não existe um valor anterior, então subtrair 99 ou qualquer outro valor não faz sentido aqui).

Se for `-1` eu sei que o salário é maior que todos os valores da lista, então basta dizer que está acima do último valor (e eu aproveito o fato de que listas aceitam índices negativos: no caso, -1 corresponde ao último elemento).

Por fim, se o valor está em alguma das faixas do meio da lista, basta pegar o valor anterior e somar 1 (em vez de subtrair 99), assim você tem uma maneira confiável de obter o intervalo, independente dos valores da lista.

---

Obviamente, os valores da lista devem estar em ordem crescente para isso tudo funcionar. Se quer garantir que ela esteja ordenada, pode usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
lista = sorted(lista)
for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
    ...
```

Ou ainda o método `sort`:

```
lista.sort()
for i, valor in enumerate(lista):
    ...
```

A diferença é que `sorted(lista)` retorna **outra** lista (ou seja, você tem a opção de manter a original intacta, bastando atribuir o resultado em outra variável), enquanto `lista.sort()` modifica a própria `lista`.

---

#### Alternativa

Uma alternativa é usar [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) para guardar os intervalos:

```
intervalos = [ range(0, 300), range(300, 400), range(400, 500), range(500, 600), range(600, 700), range(700, 800), range(800, 900), range(900, 1000) ]
sal = ... # ler salário com input(), etc
for r in intervalos:
    if sal in r:
        print(f"O funcionário está no intervalo entre {r.start} e {r.stop - 1}")
        break;
else:
    print(f"O funcionário está no intervalo acima de {intervalos[-1].stop}")
```

Um detalhe do `range` é que o primeiro valor é incluso, mas o segundo não. Então `range(300, 400)` contempla todos os números entre 300 e 399.

Em seguida, eu faço `if sal in r` para testar se o salário está contido no intervalo. Se o salário não estiver em nenhum dos intervalos, o código cai no `else` (lembrando novamente que este `else` é do `for`, não do `if`, como já explicado anteriormente).

Answer (score 0):

Para corrigir o problema, primeiro corrija os valores da sua lista. Depois defina a condicional `if` para saber se `sal` é maior ou igual a `n - 99` e menor ou igual a `n`. Se for, ele recebe o index do valor `n` na lista e sai do bloco `for`. Veja abaixo:

```
lista = [299,399,499,599,699,799,899,999]

valor_bruto = float(input("Digite o valor bruto das vendas semanais do funcionário: "))
sal = 200 + 0.09*valor_bruto #valor do salario

for n in lista:
    if n - 99 <= sal <= n:
        c = lista.index(n)
        break
print("O funcionário está no intervalo entre",lista[c]-99 ,"e",lista[c])
```